# Recursive call in binary search tree implementation in Ruby does not occur

Tags: ruby, recursion

I have implemented BST in Ruby. The iterative method works just fine, however, trying to implement a recursive implementation for the `insert` method doesn't seem to work.
For some reason, there's only 1 recursive call (i.e. depth).

Here's the method;

```
  def insert_rec(node, value)
    if node.nil?
      return Node.new(value, nil, nil)
    elsif value < node.value
      node.left ||= insert_rec(node.left, value)
    elsif value > node.value
      node.right ||= insert_rec(node.right, value)
    else
      # TODO return?
    end
  end
```

For the code above, I can call `insert` for >3 numbers, however I'll always have a tree with depth of maximum 2.

Thanks :/
Ronen

Comment: Please show your class `Node`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, `Node` is simply a struct;

`Node = Struct.new(:value, :left, :right)`

Comment: Anyone? :( bumping

Comment: Ronen, I'll have another look this evening.

Answer (score 0):

As written, you're not preserving the results of creating nodes past the top couple of levels because Ruby does pass-by-value and you don't return your updated `Node` objects.  It works if you remove the `||` from your assignments *and* return the current `Node` from your recursion:

```
def insert_rec(node, value)
  if node.nil?
    node = Node.new(value, nil, nil)
  elsif value < node.value
    node.left = insert_rec(node.left, value)
  elsif value > node.value
    node.right = insert_rec(node.right, value)
  end
  node
end
```